# Column indexing based on row value

Tags: r

I have the data frame:

```
DT=data.frame(Row=c(1,2,3,4,5),Price=c(2.1,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.5),
          '2.0'= c(100,300,700,400,0),
          '2.1'= c(400,200,100,500,0),
          '2.2'= c(600,700,200,100,200),
          '2.3'= c(300,0,300,100,100),
          '2.4'= c(400,0,0,500,600),
          '2.5'= c(0,200,0,800,100))
```

The objective is to create a new column Quantity that selects the value for each row in the column equal to Price, such that:

```
DT.Objective=data.frame(Row=c(1,2,3,4,5),Price=c(2.1,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.5),
          '2.0'= c(100,300,700,400,0),
          '2.1'= c(400,200,100,500,0),
          '2.2'= c(600,700,200,100,200),
          '2.3'= c(300,0,300,100,100),
          '2.4'= c(400,0,0,500,600),
          '2.5'= c(0,200,0,800,100),
          Quantity= c(400,200,200,100,100))
```

The dataset is very large so efficiency is important. I currently use and looking to make more efficient:

```
Names <- names(DT)
DT$Quantity<- DT[Names][cbind(seq_len(nrow(DT)), match(DT$Price, Names))]
```

For some reason the column names in the example come with an "X" in front of them, whereas in the actual data there is no X.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with row/column indexing after removing the prefix 'X' using `sub` or `substring` and then do the `match` as showed in the OP's post

```
DT$Quantity <- DT[cbind(1:nrow(DT), match(DT$Price, sub("^X", "", names(DT))))]
DT$Quantity
#[1] 400 200 200 100 100
```

---

The `X` is attached as prefix when the column names starts with numbers.  One way to take care of this would be using `check.names=FALSE` in the `data.frame` call or `read.csv/read.table`

Answer (score 1):

@akrun is correct, check.names=TRUE is the default behavior for data.frame(); from the [man page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html):

> check.names
>   logical. If TRUE then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names and are not duplicated. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are.

If possible, you may want to make your column names a bit more descriptive.